# How do I use row index to create a function based calculated column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

My df is as follows

```
BINS
SKILL      object
LOGIN      object
50.0      float64
100.0     float64
150.0     float64
200.0     float64
250.0     float64
300.0     float64
350.0     float64
400.0     float64
450.0     float64
500.0     float64
550.0     float64
600.0     float64
650.0     float64
700.0     float64
750.0     float64
800.0     float64
850.0     float64
900.0     float64
950.0     float64
1000.0    float64
dtype: object
```

Here is a sample of the data using: HMDrr.head().values

```
array([[‘Skill1’, ‘loginA’, 0.07090909090909091, 0.25, 0.35,
        0.147619047619047616, 0.057823529411764705, 0.0,
        0.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan],
       [‘Skill1’, ‘loginB’, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [‘Skill1’, ‘loginC’, 0.15, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [‘Skill1’, ‘loginD’, 0.3333333333333333,
        0.1857142857142857, 0.0, 0.15, 0.1, 0.0, 0.05666666666666667,
        0.06692307692307693, 0.05692307692307693, 0.13529411764705882, 0.1,
        0.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [‘Skill1’, ‘loginE’, 0.1, 0.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]], dtype=object)
```

I have employee data (LOGIN) by work type (SKILL).  The number columns are bins.  Each bin contains performance results for their fist 50 interactions, then 100 and so on.  I need to calculate the slope and intercept for by SKILL and LOGIN so that I can create a new employee performance ramp plan.

To do this I built the following:

```
#Bins for contacts
startBin = 0.0
stopBin = 1000.0
incrementBin = 50.0
sortBins = np.arange(startBin, stopBin + incrementBin, incrementBin)
binLabels = np.arange(startBin + incrementBin, stopBin + incrementBin, incrementBin)

#Caculate logarithimic slope in HMDrr Dataset
def calc_slope(z):
    y = HMDrr.loc[z,binLabels].dropna()
    number = y.count()+1
    y = y.values.astype(float)
    x = np.log(range(1,number,1))
    slope, intercept, r, p, stderr = linregress(x, y)
    return slope
#Caculate logarithimic intercept in HMDrr Dataset
def calc_intercept(z):
    y = HMDrr.loc[z,binLabels].dropna()
    number = y.count()+1
    y = y.values.astype(float)
    x = np.log(range(1,number,1))
    slope, intercept, r, p, stderr = linregress(x, y)
    return intercept
```

When I run either by placing the z value manually it runs fine:

```
calc_slope(10)
-0.018236067481219649
```

I want to make SLOPE and INTERCEPT columns in the df that are created using the above functions.

I have tried a variety of things such as:

```
HMDrr['SLOPE'] = calc_slope(HMDrr.index)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-717-4a58ad29d7b0> in <module>()
----> 1 HMDrr['SLOPE'] = calc_slope(HMDrr.index)

<ipython-input-704-26a18390e20c> in calc_slope(z)
      7 def calc_slope(z):
      8     y = HMDrr.loc[z,binLabels].dropna()
----> 9     x = np.log(range(1,y.count()+1,1))
     10     slope, intercept, r, p, stderr = linregress(x, y)
     11     return slope

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in wrapper(self)
     67             return converter(self.iloc[0])
     68         raise TypeError(
---> 69             "cannot convert the series to {0}".format(str(converter)))
     70     return wrapper
     71 

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'int'>
```

I also tried using the apply function, but very likely I am doing it wrong.  My guess is that I am either not applying the functions correctly for a column or the values I am getting arent integers.  I have been trying for days so now am breaking down to ask for help....

How do I generate columns using the above functions so that I get the row specific data?

Comment: can you post data for your HMDrr df, also you can debug this by looking at the type of `y` which is likely to be a df, and also what type `.count()` returns, it's a little confusing

Comment: @EdChum, thanks for the great points.  I posted a df sample.  I did a `dstypes` on `y` and found that it was a series object.  `.count` did return floats.  I modified those functions in the question so that `y` is a numpy.ndarray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While maybe not the best way to do it I solved it with the following.

Built a calc_linear function to return both slope and intercept:

```
#Caculate logarithimic slope and intercept in HMDrr Dataset
def calc_linear(z):
    y = HMDrr.loc[z,binLabels].dropna()
    number = y.count()+1
    y = y.values.astype(float)
    x = np.log(range(1,number,1))
    slope, intercept, r, p, stderr = linregress(x, y)
    return slope, intercept
```

Created empty columns for the data:

```
#Create metric columns
HMDrr['SLOPE'] = ""
HMDrr['INTERCEPT'] = ""
```

Ran a for loop to populate the columns:

```
#For loop to calculate metrics
for x in range(0,HMDrr.SLOPE.count()):
    values = calc_linear(x)
    HMDrr.SLOPE[x] = values[0]
    HMDrr.INTERCEPT[x] = values[1]
```

If there is a cleaner way then I would love to hear it :)